# Create img in specific location

Tags: jquery, append, attr

I'm trying to grab the href from a  tag, create an img and use the href as the src. Another person on this site helped with that src=href part, but i'm having difficulties creating an img with this src and appending it to a specific location. This is definitely some sort of syntax error that i can't figure out.

If i use an actual link for the src, it works somewhat.

```
$("#Results a").live('dblclick', function(event){
    if (event.type === 'dblclick') {
        var src = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#Target_Location").append('<img src=" " />').attr("src", src).addClass('DCT_Card');
    }
});
```

What happens, is that the #Target_Location is the one that gets the class, and no img is produced.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('<img />', { 'src': src, 'class': 'DCT_Card' }).appendTo('#Target_Location');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/jAPp6/).

> What if I need to wrap the `img` in a `div` with its own `class` ... after the `#Target_Location` element?

Try this...

```
$('<img />', { 'src': src, 'class': 'DCT_Card' })
 .wrap('<div class="something" />')
 .parent()     
 .insertAfter('#Target_Location');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/jAPp6/1/).

Comment: what if i need to wrap the img in a div with its own class?

Comment: @Jason You could `img.wrap('<div class="hello" />')`.

Comment: @alex how would i combine that with the above code? As well, when i said append, i meant after the #Target_Location element, not insert into.

Comment: @Jason You can insert it after by changing `appendTo` to `insertAfter`. As for combining the whole thing, see update.

Comment: @alex the placement and the img creation is perfect, but the div isn't being created: $('<img />', {'src': src,'class': 'DCT_Card Borders'}).wrap('<div class="Card_Packet" />').insertAfter($('.SH_P').parent());

Comment: @Jason You've got `insertAfter()` and `parent()` around the wrong way. Refer to the code in the answer.

Comment: @Alex ; thanks, i've got it now. I needed parent before, and parent of the target class. I have a live dbl click clone function that doesn't work on these newly generated imgs. HTML-wise, these new guys are identical to the old guys that do work. Way to 'refresh' the clone function? Should i start a new thread for this?

Comment: @Jason You probably should :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$('<img/>').attr('src', src).addClass('DCT_Card').appendTo('#Target_Location');
```

Comment: That will append `#Target_Location` to that `img` element. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/dQqLM/).

Comment: No... It won't. >.< Check @alex's [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/jAPp6/)

Comment: I believe this HTML says otherwise... `<img src="http://www.example.com/img.png" class="DCT_Card">#Target_Location</img>`